# Android dialog across Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, popup

i'm new to Android, i'm looking to find if there a Dialog feature which stays at the bottom of the application, but across different activities.(Non modal dialog) It should not loose data if the activities are changed. Thanks

Edit: For example, in google play music they have play controls floating on top of the lists.

Comment: You can make a custom dialog based on your need and use it across your application. Look at here please: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Comment: Looks like it stays on top of the application blocking the Activity view. I need something which does not block the activity and stays on top of all the activities that open without loosing the data. For example, in google play they have play controls floating on top of the lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your requirement, Add the View to the `WindowManager` when your LaucherActivity launches ,Then it ll stays until your are out from your app..

Check for more info [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995014/cannot-remove-a-view-attached-by-windowmanager-addview), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684275/adding-dynamic-view-using-windowmanager-addview), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124153/how-to-add-a-floating-view-to-android-window-manager-and-listen-to-system-hardwa)

Comment: Just to clarify, I need the dialog to stay on top of the Activities within the app that i'm developing, does this WindowManager fulfil that?

Comment: Not yet, i just want to be sure. Thanks will try and let you know.